# Extend the borders of a matrix and replicate the border elements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am given the following matrix `B`:

```
B = 

1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

I would like to pad this matrix so that there is a 1 element border that surrounds it with the border elements replicated.  Essentially, I would like this result:

```
B =                 
    1   1   4   7   7
    1   1   4   7   7
    2   2   5   8   8
    3   3   6   9   9
    3   3   6   9   9
```

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: I've edited your post to actually explain what you want done.  I hope you don't mind.  If this isn't the case, let me know and I'll roll back the changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, use [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html), specifically the `replicate` flag.  If you don't have it, there's an implementation that someone made here on Github: https://github.com/gpeyre/matlab-toolboxes/blob/master/toolbox_nlmeans/toolbox/ordfilt2/padarray.m .  You can download it and use the function for your own use.

`padarray` creates a larger matrix with the source matrix centred within this larger matrix.  You have several options on what you can do with the extra border elements.  The default behaviour is to set these equal to 0.  However, we can specify the `replicate` flag, which copies values along the original border of the matrix and places them along the extra border elements with this new matrix.  Because you want to go from 3 x 3 to 5 x 5, you just need a 1 element border along both dimensions.  You specify this with the second parameter to `padarray`.  The `replicate` flag is the third parameter:

```
>> B = reshape(1:9, 3, 3);
>> B2 = padarray(B, [1 1], 'replicate')

B2 =

     1     1     4     7     7
     1     1     4     7     7
     2     2     5     8     8
     3     3     6     9     9
     3     3     6     9     9
```

## Edit

If you don't want to use `padarray`, you can use the [`scatteredInterpolant`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html) class instead, with `nearest` as the interpolation flag.  You would build a 3 x 3 2D spatial grid of coordinates that map to each value in `B`, then we'd specify a 5 x 5 spatial grid of coordinates where the border elements are outside of the range of the original 3 x 3 grid.  Something like this:

```
>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:3,1:3);
>> [X2,Y2] = meshgrid(0:4,0:4);
>> F = scatteredInterpolant(X(:),Y(:),B(:),'nearest');
>> B2 = F(X2, Y2)

B2 =

     1     1     4     7     7
     1     1     4     7     7
     2     2     5     8     8
     3     3     6     9     9
     3     3     6     9     9
```

Comment: I want to make matrix A to Matrix B. This is a kind of mapping.

Comment: @Moussekim - Ah.  Well you didn't explain that very well.  That's easy.  Hold on.

Answer (score 1):

The question was explicitly to add a single element as border, so try this (no toolbox needed):

```
B = [1 4 7; 2 5 8; 3 6 9] % or use  B=rand(3,4), etc. to try something else.
B2 = B([1 1:end end],[1 1:end end])
```

This is the result (as desired):

```
B =
    1   4   7
    2   5   8
    3   6   9
B2 =
    1   1   4   7   7
    1   1   4   7   7
    2   2   5   8   8
    3   3   6   9   9
    3   3   6   9   9
```

Comment: As a more general solution you may want to create a function `PadN.m` with:
`function m=PadN(m,n)
r=ones(1,n);
m=m([r 1:end end*r],[r 1:end end*r]);
end`